# PHP/HTML forms and database inserting

Tags: php, html, database, forms, mysqli

I am going to start this off by saying -- yes I know there are other links similar to this and topics similar to this and I have read all of them and incorporated them into my code. However, I cannot figure it out and have tried everything I can.

Basically my goal is to take a users input from an html form called socialmedia.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> Pulse submission page </h1><br>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
Title: <input type="text" name="posttitle"><br><br>
Content: <input type="text" name="content"><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and then send it to a php file called action.php:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("DB HOST IP", "USER", "PASS", "DB NAME");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";



$posttitle = $_POST["posttitle"];
$content = $_POST["content"];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$sql = "INSERT INTO `posts` (posttitle, content) VALUES ('$posttitle', '$content')";
echo 'post added to database';
}
if($sql){
echo 'success';
}
else{
echo 'failure';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts`";

$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

if($res->num_rows > 0){
 while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
 echo "ID". $row["id"]. "<br/>";
 echo "Title". $row["posttitle"]. "<br/>";
 echo "Content". $row["content"]. "<br/>";
 }
}
else
{
 echo "No Record Found!";
}
?>
```

This file is SUPPOSED to insert the user's form values into the table `posts`:
[this is the table posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCK42.png)

and then print the whole table to a webpage-- action.php this is what it prints (with the error checks and all):

[this is the page, I blurred out the IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb8jU.png)

NOTE: I manually inserted the first title and content to see if the code could read from the database (which it can)

honestly, I do not know where I went wrong and I have die extensive research at this point. It's probably going to end up being a syntax error and I'm gonna be kicking myself. It could have something to do with me using a Godaddy server and the phpMyAdmin and database being through there. I am using mysqli instead of PDO because PLESK and Godaddy do not support PDO yet.

Comment: Is that **exact** line `$mysqli = new mysqli("DB HOST IP", "USER", "PASS, "DB NAME");` exist in your code?

Comment: @AlonEitan no i just took out my info its an actual IP though not localhost

Comment: Yes, but did you also forget to close the password string in your code too?

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @AlonEitan no sorry I didn't just edited it wrong when changing the values here

Comment: And do you also not executing any insert query in your code, and just saving it into a variable named `$sql`?

Comment: You are not executing the insert statement, you just assign it to a variable

Comment: can you comment this line from your code...."echo $mysqli->host_info"

Comment: would that be $mysqli->query($sql);  @Comforse

Comment: what would that do? just get rid of the info on the page? @SachinAghera

Comment: just try and check

Answer (score -2, accepted):

several things to get you started
1) missing quote after PASS

```
 mysqli("DB HOST IP", "USER", "PASS, "DB NAME");
```

2) you are not executing your INSERT query, missing $mysqli->query($sql);

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$sql = "INSERT INTO `posts` (posttitle, content) VALUES ('$posttitle', 
'$content')";
echo 'post added to database';
}
```

Comment: I just input this right after the $sql = ... statement but still nothing

Comment: Also $_POST['submit'] this does not exists, since your submit button does not have a name.

Comment: You are welcome, its the little things causes the big problems we fail to see.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="submit" name="submit" />` try with this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `posts` (posttitle, content) VALUES ('$posttitle', '$content')";
   $save = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if($save)
        echo 'success';
    else
        echo 'failure';
}
```

Comment: That is the correct answer, but the OP must look into http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php if they don't want to get their website hacked

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks. Yes, You are right, must be secured from sql injection.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

You have to give name of the submit butto as

> input type="submit" name="submit"

```
"INSERT INTO  posts (posttitle, content) VALUES ('$posttitle', '$content')"
```